# Custom slug for Custom Post Type - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My required slug for the custom post type:

```
https://codehelppro.com/detail/PARENT-POST/SLUG
```

I have registered a custom post type.

```
add_action('init', 'chplms_examples');

 function chplms_examples(){
    register_post_type('detail', array(
        'label' => 'Tutorial Details',
        'labels' => array(
            'add_new_item' => 'Tutorial Details',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Tutorial Details',
        ),
        'rewrite'                => array(
            'slug'               => 'detail/%tutorial_slug%',
            'with_front'         => false
        ),
        'public'                 => true,  // If you don't want it to make public, make it false
        'publicly_queryable'     => true,  // you should be able to query it
        'show_ui'                => true,  // you should be able to edit it in wp-admin
        'has_archive'            => true,    //true,
        'supports'               => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
        'show_in_rest' => true
    ));
}
```

I have replaced `%tutorial_slug%` using post_parent slug.

```
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type == 'detail'){
        $cats = get_post($post->post_parent);
        if (!empty($cats->post_name))
            $link = str_replace('%tutorial_slug%', $cats->post_name, $link);
    }
    return $link;

}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

Permalink is showing right in the admin dashboard or when I check on the "VIEW" link, It returns 404 pages.